# Fantastic elastic search plugin, no search results

Tags: elasticsearch, wordpress

The query generated by the [Fantastic ES plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fantastic-elasticsearch) always returns no results for a search. The SQL statement generated by the query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
  AND wp_posts.ID IN (0)
  AND wp_posts.post_type IN (\'post\', \'page\',\'attachment\', \'events\', \'testimonies\', \'leadership\') 
  AND (wp_posts.post_status = \'publish\' OR wp_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_posts.post_status = \'private\') 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_type ASC 
LIMIT 0, 500'
```

It always has `wp_posts.ID IN (0)` which would seem to always be false? All the posts are in elasticsearch and I am able to run queries on the data from the command line. I am new to Elasticsearch and this plugin, maybe I am missing something simple?

Comment: At first glance, if you see your Wordpress querying your DB using SQL it means it's not searching in your Elasticsearch server (which can happen if the latter is down or unresponsive). Are you sure you configured and activated your plugin correctly?

Comment: I was just dumping the query using:
`<?php echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request; ?>`  
The plugin seems to be running because I get the normal LIKE query when I turn off the plugin.  I do have wordpress in a sub-directory, and there seems to be a good chance that this is what is confusing fantastic elastic search.